# Show number of prepaid and COD orders on vendor panel

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-vendor

I Want to show the number of **COD** and **prepaid orders** on vendor panel dashboard. Can any body please help me how to do it and code for the same. I am using ced commerce marketplace extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can the order collection by and then add filter to get the desired collection than from the collection you can get the count.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->join(
        array('payment' => 'sales/order_payment'),
        'main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id',
        array('payment_method' => 'payment.method')
    );
```

then you can add filter

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('payment.method', array(array('nlike' => 'paypal')))
->addFieldToFilter('state', array(array('like' => 'processing')));
```

or

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('payment.method', array('neq' => 'paypal'))
->addFieldToFilter('state', 'processing')
```